Vite React client app returns 404 errors in Vercel's vercel dev deployment
I am building a fullstack app with Vite, React, React Router and deploying it on Vercel.
Deploying the client app to production on Vercel works absolutely fine.
But now, I am in the process of implementing serverless functions in the same project on Vercel (using the API folder). To test the fullstack app before deploying it I am using vercels CLI tool and the vercel dev command.
When I run it I get the following 404 errors when accessing the client application.

The serverless API endpoints work on the other hand:

Why is the Vite frontend app returning 404 errors? How can I fix it?
Another thing I noticed is that when I remove the vercel.json config file, it then works! But I need the config file in order for React Routers routing to work. Here the config file:
{
    "rewrites": [
        {
            "source": "/api/(.*)",
            "destination": "/api/$1"
        },
        {
            "source": "/(.*)",
            "destination": "/"
        }
    ]
}

What exactly causes the vercel dev deployment to mess up the Vite client application? The dev command remains kind of a black-box for me.

I found the answer. I had to use routes instead of rewrites in the vercel.json
{
"routes": [
    {
        "src": "/api/(.*)",
        "dest": "/api/$1"
    },
    {
        "src": "/(.*)",
        "dest": "/"
    }
]

}
